# setComponentEnabledSetting causes an exception,it may kill current app?

Tags: android, android-activity

i am willing to disable one activity from another activity by following codes,but it causes a problem: kill current app.
   the SDK version is 4.0 .

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

     pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(newComponentName(this,
                                    "com.xxx.launcher.desktop.testActivity"),
                                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,   
                                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

}

is it lack of sth to be set?

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#DONT_KILL_APP

You have to be a little careful when you use `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP`, as it can lead to undefined behavior. Especially if the activity is trying to disable itself. It should be fine if you're targeting another Activity, but I'm guessing the Activity you're trying to clear is in the

It looks like your call to `ComponentName` is incorrect. 
You will probably want to call `new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), testActivity.class)`. Or you can use `new ComponentName("com.xxx.launcher.desktop","com.xxx.launcher.desktop.testActivity")`, where the first argument is the package in the AndroidManifest.xml file, and the second being the full path to the `ComponentName`. Take a look at the following SO question for information on setting up a ComponentName: [When to use which constructor for ComponentName in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985859) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP.

I noticed, at the top of the **Run** window in Android Studio, that it wasn't trying to launch my default launcher activity, **SplashActivity**, but another launcher activity within my app:

```
Launching 'app' on samsung SM-J320FN.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example/com.example.NotMyDefaultLauncherActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

My app exited unceremoniously when it later attempted to disable **NotMyDefaultLauncherActivity** (via `packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(...)`.

The solution for me was to go into **Run** > **Edit Configurations...** > **Android App** > **app**, where I changed the launch activity from **DefaultActivity** to (what should have been the default, as it was the first one listed in my manifest) `com.example.SplashActivity`.