# Enable and Disable service programmatically in android not working

Tags: android, service

I am using fcm service for push notifications.In my app i have choice for opting notifications for that what i have done i used component to enable and disable service programatically so that if user opts for notifcation i will enable it otherwise disable but it is not working.

code:

```
       public  void disableComponent(){
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, MyFirebaseMesagingService.class),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }
        public  void enableComponent() {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, MyFirebaseMesagingService.class),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }
     <service
                android:name=".MyFirebaseMesagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
i tried with this still not working

 public  void disableComponent(){
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.example.sgorle.fcmsampleapp", "com.example.sgorle.fcmsampleapp.MyFirebaseMesagingService"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
    public  void enableComponent() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.example.sgorle.fcmsampleapp", "com.example.sgorle.fcmsampleapp.MyFirebaseMesagingService"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: recheck your ComponentName. it will work

Comment: i checked so many times it is not working,after disabling fcm service also notification receiving

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986081/1697047

Comment: i edited my code check it still not working please help me